# Windows 7 Backup over VPN

Tags: windows-7, backup, vpn

Is it possible to schedule a backup to a network share through VPN using Windows 7 built-in backup app. I.e. before starting backup, Windows backup should establish a VPN connection and then proceed to backup on the network that becomes available?

Comment: You'll have to write a script of some sort to connect and then begin the backup. Windows Backup itself won't be able to make the connection first.

Answer (score 2):

As Randolph said, you will probably need a script to establish [VPN first](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754216%28WS.10%29.aspx) and then you can use [wbadmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015%28WS.10%29.aspx) to run windows backup via commandline.

You can then use taskscheduler to call this script

Answer (score 1):

I have personally never tried this, but it should be possible...

Even if you are not using Internet Explorer, you will need to open `Internet Options`.

From this screen, make sure your VPN is listed and choose "Always dial my default connection`or`Dial whenever a network connection is not present`.

Next time, when your machine attempts to contact the network IP, the machine should dial your default connection (VPN).

I really wouldn't recommend this though and I am not entirely sure it will work as I have not had to use these options for years.

[image]

Alternatively, I would recommend using a backup tool such as [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm), and set up a script that automatically connects the VPN before backup starts.